# C++ template function for arrays, vectors, built in types, STL

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to make a class that has a function that saves the data sent to it, to a text file.  The data that can be passed to it can be anything like a `std::string`, `int`, `double`, `float`, `unsigned int`, etc., and can also be an: `std::vector<T>`, `T[]`, and `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, `T[][]`.

Now, obviously if it is an array, I will need to iterate through it to send the data to text-file.

I was thinking of using templates, but I'm not sure how to do the arrays.

Is this the way to go?

```
class CMyClass
{
    template<typename T>
    void SaveData(T data);
    void SaveData(std::vector<T> data);
    void SaveData(std::string data);
    void SaveData(T* data);                // Perhaps I'll also need to pass in the size.
    void SaveData(std::vector<std::vector<T>> data);
    void SaveData(T** data);
};
```

I imagine that the code for the `std::string` would be the same as the code for the `std::vector<T>` provided that `T` is a built in type (like an `int` or `float` or something).

And then I write the functions for each of the `SaveData(...)` accordingly?

Comment: Your title is very broad and vague, you may want to rephrase it.

Comment: FYI:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Also: https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can either template the class or the functions. Since you want to do arrays as well, you **must** go with the latter option. Example follows:

```
class CMyClass
{
public:
    template<typename T> void SaveData(const T &data);
    template<typename T, size_t N> void SaveData(const T (&data)[N]);
    template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M> void SaveData(const T (&data)[N][M]);
    template<typename T> void SaveData(const std::vector<T> &data);
    template<typename T> void SaveData(const std::vector<std::vector<T> > &data);
    void SaveData(const std::string &data);
};
```

Once you have defined the functions, the following example shows how you can call them:

```
int i;
int i1[5];
int i2[5][7];
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v2;
std::string s;

CMyClass saveClass;

saveClass.SaveData<int>(i);
saveClass.SaveData<int>(i1);
saveClass.SaveData<int>(i2);
saveClass.SaveData<int>(v1);
saveClass.SaveData<int>(v2);
saveClass.SaveData(s);
```

Depending on your requirements, you could make the class a singleton and the functions static, omitting the need to instantiate CMyClass at all and simply calling the functions as follows:

```
CMyClass::SaveData<int>(i);
CMyClass::SaveData<int>(i1);
CMyClass::SaveData<int>(i2);
CMyClass::SaveData<int>(v1);
CMyClass::SaveData<int>(v2);
CMyClass::SaveData(s);
```

**Notes:**

1. The arguments should also be references (i.e. "&data" rather than "data"), so that only the reference is passed rather than performing a copy of the whole container each time you call the function.
2. I've explicitly declared the functions as public, assuming this is the complete class and its functions will be accessed by another class. By default, the members of a class are private.
3. Ensure that there is a space between each nested ">".

**Good luck!**

Comment: Thank you do much!  That really helps.  I have one question though, why did you use the word array instead of data?  Is it just a naming thing, or... does it do something, because I read that only in VS does it do something.

Comment: My use of "array" as the variable name was just a force of habit. I've edited the code so that it's now "data" to maintain interface consistency. Don't worry, "array" is not a keyword in C++. Sorry for any confusion that may have caused!

Comment: Thank you, one last question, to implement std::vector<std::string> >, I'd have to make a seperate overload again, wouldn't I, despite the fact that the method would possible the same as the one for std::vector<std::vector<T> >?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're mixing two things in one class, which should be avoided: As far as I can see, what your class is about (its "responsibility") is to write data to a file. Another thing you're adding is knowledge about iterating collections of data.

Take a look at STL's `<algorithm>` methods:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

There you can find generic ways of iterating data, e.g. in the `find` method:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value )
  {
    for ( ;first!=last; first++) if ( *first==value ) break;
    return first;
  }
```

This makes you independent from whether you are using `vector`, `list`, arrays or whatever.

If you also want to serialize things like `vector<vector<T> >` (note the space between the two `>`!), you have to explain more on what you want to do with such data. Simply concat the elements as if all `T`s were in one `vector`? In this case you might try to create a new iterator which does exactly this.

The boost iterator library could help with this:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  To elaborate, I would like to write whatever is passed in, to a text file in this fashion: ifstream ifs ( "test.txt" , ifstream::in ); ifs << data.  If data is a vector<T>, then I have to iterate over it, if data is an int, then I don't.  If data is a T[][] then I have to iterate over that too...  I am aware of std::algorithm and functions such as for_each(...); however, I don't see how they would help if the user passes in an int or a char.  Also, I don't believe I can use std::for_each for things like std::vector< std::vector<T> >.