# Can you make a template that will accept vectors and arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

I know you can create templates to make functions accept int, double, float. But can you "templatize" a function so that it can accept both arrays and vectors?

Comment: Kind-of. The easy way is to provide templates that take a pair of iterators specifying a valid range.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373363/c-template-function-for-arrays-vectors-built-in-types-stl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual answer would be to write a single template function that takes a pair of iterators as parameters. Because pointers are iterators too you can call your function with the pointers to the first and one past the end elements of the array.

E.g.

```
template <class II>
void print_all(II first, II last)
{
  for (II i = first; i != last; ++i)
    cout << *i << ' ';
  cout << '\n';
}

vector<int> v;
int a[10];
...
print_all(v.begin(), v.end());
print_all(a, a + 10);
```

Comment: `print_all(std::begin(a), std::end(a))`

Comment: print_all(begin(a), end(a))
you should be using ADL in case my custom type defines it's own begin() and end() functions.